# Counting the total number of words in of rows of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with words in every row. Example of some rows:

```
df
This is a word
Another word
third word
word
```

And I want to count the number of each row and write it to a new data frame and have in a final csv something like this:

```
df,total
This is a word,4
Another word,2
third word,2
word,1
```

Possible using the space character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use `strsplit` with the split you wish and then count the number of items which come out.

```
df$total <- sapply(df$df, function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\W+"))))
```

gives me the following output:

```
              df total
1 This is a word     4
2   Another word     2
3     third word     2
4           word     1
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
df$total <- str_count(df$df, '\\s+')+1
df$total
#[1] 4 2 2 1
```

Or

```
 nchar(gsub('[^ ]+', '',df$df))+1
 #[1] 4 2 2 1
```

Or

```
 lengths(strsplit(df$df, '\\S+'))
 #[1] 4 2 2 1
```

Or

```
 count.fields(textConnection(df$df))
 #[1] 4 2 2 1
```

Comment: `lengths(gregexpr("[[:>:]]",df$df,perl=TRUE))` for detecting words separated by commas, spaces, fullstops, and combinations of these characters.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks, but it gives me error `Error in gregexpr("[[:>:]]", df$df, perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '[[:>:]]'`  Is there any typo?

Comment: @thelatemail I am using `R 3.2.1`

Comment: works for me - i'm back on 3.1.0 - `gregexpr("[[:>:]]",df$df,perl=TRUE)` seems to work just fine, `lengths` won't on this old version, but I'm assuming that works fine with an up-to-date version. The error seems to be around the `gregexpr` call though, which is odd.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it is just the `[[:>:]]` that creates the trouble

Comment: @thelatemail It also had a warning `In addition: Warning message:
In gregexpr("[[:>:]]", df$df, perl = TRUE) : PCRE pattern compilation error
 'unknown POSIX class name'
 at '>:]]'`

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, it might have to do with the specific regex engine?

Comment: @thelatemail That could be the case. I am on linux mint 17.  Thanks for your input